# Formmail returning recipient not found issue

Tags: html, forms, formmail

I am trying to build a form, and I am using my providers built in formmail (which is basic formmail)  I am told that it is configured to accept images as part of the formmail.  When I run the form without the Enctype tag, it works it just does not send the image.  Upon research I learned that you need to add the enctype="multipart/form-data" tag onto the form, it will allow the image to be sent with the form.  Once I add the enctype tag, I get this error, however my recipient field is filled out and it DOES work if I do not use the enctype tag, however I can't send files.  I will also note I do not have access to my providers formmail.pl.

Error: Bad/No Recipient
There was no recipient or an invalid recipient specified in the data sent to FormMail. Please make sure you have filled in the recipient form field with an e-mail address that has been configured in @recipients. More information on filling in recipient form fields and variables can be found in the README file.
FormMail V1.92 © 1995 - 2002 Matt Wright
A Free Product of Matt's Script Archive, Inc.

Below is my HTML.

```
  <div class="container" id="indexbody">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="content trophy">
          <h3 class="h3-seo sechead">Ordering</h3>
          <hr>
          <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="http://hometeamsupply.com/cgi-bin/formmail">
            <p>
              <label style="margin-right: 100px">Name:
              <input type="text" name="name" size=30 required>
              </label> 
              <label>E-mail: 
              <input type="email" name="email_address" size=30 required>
              </label>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Catalog:</label>
              <select name="catalog">
                <optgroup label="Apparel & Accessories">
                  <option>Pennant Sportwear 2018</option>
                  <option>Alphaborder Apparel & Accessories</option>
                  <option>SanMar Apparel, Bags, & Caps</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Trophies, Awards & Engravables">
                  <option>Corporate Awards & Gifts</option>
                  <option>Sports Awards & Gifts</option>
                  <option>General Awards</option>
                  <option>Engravables & Gifts</option>
                  <option>Trophies & Accessories</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Workwear & School Jackets">
                  <option>GAME Workwear & School Jackets</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Uniforms and Teamwear">
                  <option>Badger Sports 2018</option>
                  <option>Augusta/Holloway/High-Five 2018</option>
                  <option>Alphaborder Team 365</option>
                  <option>Teamwork Athletic Apparel</option>
                </optgroup>
              </select>
            </p>
            <p>
            <label>Order:</label><br>
            <textarea name="order" placeholder="Enter Order Here" rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea>
            </p>
            <p>
            <label>Logo Upload:</label><br>
            <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"> 
            </p>
            <p><button>Submit</button>   <button type="Reset">Reset</button></p> 
            <br>
            <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="recipient" VALUE="donrobinson@hometeamsupply.com">
            <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="HTS Online Order - E-Commerce"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="title" value="HTS Online Order - E-Commerce"> 
            <input type=hidden name="redirect" value="http://www.hometeamsupply.com/HTSthanks.htm">
            <input type="hidden" name="return_link_url" value="http://www.hometeamsupply.com/HTSthanks.htm"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="return_link_title" value="http://www.hometeamsupply.com/HTSthanks.htm"> 
            <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="email" VALUE="postmaster@hometeamsupply.com">
            <input type="hidden" name="background" value=""> 
            <input type=hidden name="required" value="name,email,order">
            <input type=hidden name="sort" value="order:="name,email,catalog,order,file"> 
             <!--End private fields--> 
            <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="env_report" VALUE="REMOTE_HOST,REMOTE_ADDR,HTTP_USER_AGENT"></p> 
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: We need to know how this is progressed and for that we need the code shown in `<form action="ThisFileContainsCodeShowThisToUs">`...

Comment: That's the problem I was running into also, I dont have access to that file, as I am using my  providers formmail, and it's not on the FTP. I asked them about the configuration and was told that it was setup correctly.  However I don't know if I can really trust that

Comment: There are many other formemails on the internet. Use that instead. It's actually not so difficult to use.

Comment: Do you have any good suggestions?  Before I used the providers formmail I did build a form and found my own, however I could not attach files and was having a hard time finding one that would and was free.

Comment: I am actually trying to build my very own that accept multi fileupload. However you should store the files on a server and send an email containing the path to the files (and the other submitted info). That is my approach. Also to get what I want I will use jQuery, PHP and HTML forms. Never forget to validate your inputs AND (re)captcha your users ;)

Comment: yea this is my first form that I am building as part of my first website I am doing all together so It's definitely been an experience. :)